# "Cannot format given Object as a Number" al mostrar JTable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Saludoss, tengo un problemilla al mostrar el contenido de una base de datos en una tabla JTable, en un proyecto .java usando netbeans.

He intentado observar la salida de la columna con la que me da error, se trata de la 5ª columna un dato de tipo Float, la 4ª posición del String[], y los datos que me devuelve son correctos....

Con lo que no consigo saber porque me aborta con este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507)
at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
at javax.swing.JTable$DoubleRenderer.setValue(JTable.java:5356)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(DefaultTableCellRenderer.java:257)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5723)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5217)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1042)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1975)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3904)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:842)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Este es el código que estoy utilizando, en concreto un método que lo llamo en el constructor de la ventana, que me rellena el Listado con los datos de la database..

```
private void rellenaListado() {
    //Pido a la base de datos los datos de la tabla articulo
    DefaultTableModel dtm = devuelveDTM();

    //Pido a la base da datos los datos de la tabla articulo
    String[] datos = new String[dtm.getColumnCount()];

    //Crear un objeto DataBase
    DataBase db = new DataBase();

    //Crear un objeto ResultSet y lo inicializamos a null
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        //Abrimos la conexión
        db.abrirConexion();
        //Creamos la consulta
        String consulta = "SELECT * FROM articulo;";
        //Ejecutamos la consulta, para eso necesitamos un objeto ResultSet
        rs = db.ejecutaConsulta(consulta);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Recorro el ResultSet
            datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
            datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
            datos[2] = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(3));
            datos[3] = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(4));
            datos[4] = String.format("%5.2f", rs.getFloat(5));
            dtm.addRow(datos);
        }
    } catch (MyException | SQLException ex) {
        VentanaNotificaciones.ventanaError(ex.getMessage(), padre);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                //Cierro el ResultSet
                db.cierraResult(rs);
            }
            //Cierro la conexión con la base de datos
            db.cerrarConexion();
        } catch (MyException ex) {
            VentanaNotificaciones.ventanaError(ex.getMessage(), padre);
        }
    }
}
```

He comprobado con estos chivatos las salidas pero me sale el contenido de la tabla correcto...

```
            //Comienzo de pruebas (chivatos)
            System.out.println("Pos 0 Array:" + datos[0]);
            System.out.println("Pos 1 Array:" + datos[1]);
            System.out.println("Pos 2 Array:" + datos[2]);
            System.out.println("Pos 3 Array:" + datos[3]);
            System.out.println("String.format:" + String.format("%5.2f", rs.getFloat(5)));
            System.out.println("rs.getFloat(5):" + rs.getFloat(5));

            String s = String.format("%5.2f", rs.getFloat(5));
            String replace = s.replace(" ","");
            datos[4] = String.format("%5.2f", replace);

            System.out.println("Pos 4 Array:" + datos[4]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna que presenta problemas es la siguiente, si comento la línea no aborta pero, y obviamente no muestra el precio de tipo float:

```
datos[4] = String.format("%5.2f", rs.getFloat("5"));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias a todos de ante mano, y a ver si me podeis echar un cable.

Comment: Trataste:            `datos[4] = String.format("%5.2f", rs.getFloat(5));`?

Comment: Lo primero agradecerte tu pronta respuesta, y lo segundo pedirte disculpas porque ha sido un error de escritura, rs.getFloat(5) lo ejecuto SIN comillas dobles.No obstante cuando pongo la línea que me indicas sin comentar me aborta con el cód de error que muestro en el primer campo de código. En cambio si comento dicha línea me devuelve el resto de contenido de la BBDD en la JTable como muestro en la última imagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el mensaje de la excepción dice:

> Cannot format given Object as a Number

Eso significa que en el modelo de datos ([`javax.swing.table.TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)) se está definiendo que en cierta columna se recibirá un tipo de dato específico. Sin embargo, los datos en el modelo para esa columna en particular no contienen *ese* tipo de dato específico, sino que son de *otro* tipo.

Es decir, que el método `getColumnClass` del modelo devuelve `Double.class` para ese índice en específico:

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        ...
        case 4:
            return Double.class;
        ...
    }
}
```

No obstante, tú estás poniendo en esa columna un cadena, un `String` cuando debes poner un `Double` o `double`. No es posible hacer casting de `String` a `Number`.

Hay dos posibles solucones: cambiar el tipo de dato devuelto en `getColumnClass` a `String.class` o cambiar el tipo de dato en los *datos* (dejarlo como `float`). En el último caso, se *renderizaría* con el formato por defecto y no con el formato que has indicado (`"%5.2f"`).

<sup>……………………………

Para más información, veáse la sección [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) en [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) dentro de [*The Java™ Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).</sup>